# How to properly configure static folder for django's admin files

Tags: django, nginx

I have deployed project on production (django+gunicorn+nginx)
My project structure is as follows

```
forecast # this dir of os.path.join(Base_Dir)
    manage.py
    forecast 
        settings.py
        urls.py
    static 
        admin
            css
            fonts
            img
        css
        js
```

In settings.py static folder configured as follows

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'                         
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
```

While i am trying to login to admin page it's return me `500 server error`. Than i tried to see what in my nginx logs `/var/log/nginx/error.log.1` 
There are following

```
2020/02/20 13:01:53 [error]   
11703#11703: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/home/isli/projects/forecast/static/static/admin/css/base.css"    
failed (2: No such file or directory), 
client: 188.170.195.79, server: isli.site, 
request: "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1", host: "isli.site",    
referrer: "http://isli.site/admin/login/?next=/admin/"
```

In nginx settings `/etc/nginx/sites-available/forecast` static files location is as follow

```
location /static/ {          
      root /home/isli/projectsforecast;
}
```

According to nginx logs

```
"/usr/share/nginx/home/isli/projects/forecast/static/static/admin/css/base.css"
```

in path to static files inserted static twice and i can't catch where this insertion occurs

Comment: What is the value of your `BASE_DIR`? It seems like its adding the `static` twice since the server is trying to open `.../projects/forecast/static/static/admin/...`

Comment: @KathyRindhoops i edited my question with addition where os.path.join(BASE_DIR) pointed